# Syntax of account names when using the cacls command

Tags: windows

I have been trying to figure out how to get available usernames for the [cacls /g username:right](http://thedance.net/~win95/cacls.html) command to grant specific users permissions for files and directories. I am at a bit of a roadblock, because some accounts such as the SYSTEM account exist on my machine:

```
C:\Windows\system32>wmic sysaccount get Name
...
SYSTEM
...
```

But the /g option of cacls will only work with `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`, so it needs the NT AUTHORITY domain prefix. The question I have is, how can I determine this prefix for any account, such as SYSTEM from my wmic query? How can you get all available account names for use with the /g option of cacls?

I did find that SysInternals (of course, the masters of low level OS tools) have a tool called [psgetsid](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/sysinternals/bb897417.aspx) which will spit out the SID of the SYSTEM account along with its other alias, `NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM`, but I was hoping there would be a more standard way of getting this name out of the box:

```
C:\Users\User\Downloads\PSTools>psgetsid SYSTEM

PsGetSid v1.44 - Translates SIDs to names and vice versa
Copyright (C) 1999-2008 Mark Russinovich
Sysinternals - www.sysinternals.com

SID for NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM:
S-1-5-18
```

Answer (score 2):

Run the following PowerShell script:

```
# Normal users:
get-wmiobject -class "win32_account" -namespace "root\cimv2" | where-object{$_.sidtype -eq 1} | sort name | foreach {Write-Host $env:computername\$($_.Name)}
# Normal groups:
get-wmiobject -class "win32_account" -namespace "root\cimv2" | where-object{$_.sidtype -eq 4} | where-object{$_.sid.length -gt 15} | sort name | foreach {Write-Host $env:computername\$($_.Name)}
# Builtin groups:
get-wmiobject -class "win32_account" -namespace "root\cimv2" | where-object{$_.sidtype -eq 4 -and $_.SID -Match "^S-1-5-32-(\d){3}$" } | sort name | foreach {Write-Host BUILTIN\$($_.Name)}
# Special accounts:
get-wmiobject -class "win32_account" -namespace "root\cimv2" | where-object{$_.sidtype -eq 5} | sort name | foreach {Write-Host NT AUTHORITY\$($_.Name)}
# Service accounts:
get-service | foreach {Write-Host NT Service\$($_.Name)}
# only if you have IIS with scripting installed:
Get-WebConfiguration system.applicationHost/applicationPools/* | where {$_.ProcessModel.identitytype -eq 'ApplicationPoolIdentity'} | foreach {Write-Host IIS APPPOOL\$($_.Name)}
# Only if you have Hyper-V installed
get-vm | foreach {Write-Host NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\$($_.Id)}

# Odd ones:
"NT VIRTUAL MACHINE\Virtual Machines"
"NT AUTHORITY\Local account and member of Administrators group"
"NT AUTHORITY\Local account"
"NT AUTHORITY\This Organization Certificate"
"APPLICATION PACKAGE AUTHORITY\ALL APPLICATION PACKAGES"
"CONSOLE LOGON"
```

This is for a local machine only, in a AD domain there are more accounts, there is more information in [my answer over on superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/248315/list-of-hidden-virtual-windows-user-accounts/638376)